# Is it possible to run a schedule in Foundry without View permissions on all input datasets?

Tags: palantir-foundry

In the following scenario:

- Admin User sets up a schedule with multiple input datasets in Input Project and output in the Output Project
- End User only has access to the Output Project containing an Output Dataset

Can End User manually run the schedule that includes building multiple datasets from Input Project and ultimate target of Output Dataset?

I'm reviewing [the docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/create-schedule/#build-scope) on the schedule's build scope but still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- All of the input datasets from other projects are [added as references](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/code-repositories/use-project-references/) in the Output project
- The user has write access to the Output project

Then a [project-scoped schedule](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/building-pipelines/create-schedule/#project-scoping) created to build the Output dataset will be runnable by the user.